# Hover text over a responsive image

Tags: css, fade

I'm looking to get the same effect from the images on hover on this site: http://www.cssdesignawards.com/website-of-the-day-award-winners.php

The images are responsive and when hovered, they show text and a purple background fade in.

Does anyone know the code to reproduce this effect?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about requesting code directly.

Comment: look into css hover states and play around a bit. Come back with a fiddle if you get stuck on something more specific.

Comment: Also Chrome devTools are you best friend. Check out the CSS styles from the example site you gave us.

Comment: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/06/18/caption-hover-effects/

Nice tutorial on same topic.. Also to clarify, the technology used is css3 and quite possibly some javascript thrown in.. these are the area you want to look i didnt downvote but asking for code straight up is considered bad form! :( Try show your work first! :) Welcome to SO

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/rx69vw89/)

*Include* `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` *in your header before the execution of your other jQuery scripts*

*Link from above script tag from https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide for most recent release of Google's Hosted jQuery Library.*

---

Next time you ask a question, include code you have, code you have tried and a jsfiddle (http://www.jsfiddle.net). Your question will likely be accepted by the stackoverflow community.
Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information about how to properly ask a question on stackoverflow. **Do not ask for people to "make" code for you if you have not demonstrated that you've already tried to do so yourself.**

---

You're lucky I'm **Canadian**, anyway here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <img class="imagesWithHover" src="http://placehold.it/300" />
    <div class="showMeOnImageHover">
        <div class="contentHolder">
            <div class="title">My Title</div>
            <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <img class="imagesWithHover" src="http://placehold.it/300" />
    <div class="showMeOnImageHover">
        <div class="contentHolder">
            <div class="title">My Other Title</div>
            <div class="content">My other content is here yay it looks so nice woohoo</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.showMeOnImageHover {
    background-color:rgba(170, 0, 170, 0.3);
    font-family:Arial;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    display:table-cell;
    position:absolute;
}
.showMeOnImageHover>.contentHolder {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    margin:10px;
}
.showMeOnImageHover .title {
    font-size:30px;
}
.showMeOnImageHover .content {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

**JS**

```
var numberOfImages = $(".imagesWithHover").length;
var numberOfDivOverlays = $(".showMeOnImageHover").length;
for (var i = 0; i < numberOfDivOverlays; i++) {
    var width = $(".imagesWithHover:eq(" + i + ")").width();
    var height = $(".imagesWithHover:eq(" + i + ")").height();
    var left = $(".imagesWithHover:eq(" + i + ")").position().left;
    var top = $(".imagesWithHover:eq(" + i + ")").position().top;
    $(".showMeOnImageHover:eq(" + i + ")").css({
        width: width,
        height: height,
        left: left,
        top: top
    });
}
$(".showMeOnImageHover").css("opacity", 0);
$(".showMeOnImageHover").hover(function () {
    $(this).animate({
        "opacity": 1
    }, 500);
}, function () {
    $(this).animate({
        "opacity": 0
    }, 500);
});
```

---

Note: the way I'm getting the *width, height, left, top* properties using jQuery, the **index of each element** with class name `.showMeOnImageHover` **will match the index of the image** with the class `.imagesWithHover` (where **index** is the index of the specific item within the class it belongs to - as per the lines: `var numberOfImages = $(".imagesWithHover").length;` **and** `var numberOfDivOverlays = $(".showMeOnImageHover").length;`). So if you have 30 images, and only 29 divs with the respective class names, only the first 29 images will have a div when you hover them. If you want to change this, you can get the properties by getting the siblings of the respective divs using something like the following code:

```
var property = $(".showMeOnImageHover").siblings(".imagesWithHover").property;
```

where `property` is the property you wish to access *(width, height, left, top)*

Comment: "You're luck i'm Canadian" :D Y U NO GRAMMER SKILLZ THEN! :D

Comment: @Pogrindis Oops typo lol thanks

Comment: :) Happens to the best of us! Good answer anyway i like that you explained good practices to asking questions here!